# Regex to match hours and time

Tags: regex, perl

I'm still learning Perl regular expressions and I need to match a string that represents the time.

However there are instances where multiple times get entered.  Instead of '9AM' I will sometimes get '9AM5PM' or '09AM05PM' and so on...  Fortunately, It always starts with one or two numbers and ends with 'AM' or 'PM' (Upper and Lowercase)

Here's what I have so far:

```
$string =~ /^((([1-9])|(1[0-2]))*(A|P)M)$/i;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.27/Piece.pm#Date_Parsing

Comment: Please explain the problems you are having with the code that you have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see with your own code is that the hours field is optional (because you use a `*`) but you don't say what issues you're having.

You do have a lot of unnecessary *captures*. Every part of the pattern that is enclosed in parentheses will capture the corresponding part of the target string in an internal variables called `$1`, `$2` etc. Unless you really need those captures it is best to use non-capturing parentheses `(?: ... )` instead of the plain ones `( ... )`.

Character classes like `[1-9]` are a single entity and don't need enclosing in parentheses. You also haven't accounted for a leading zero on values less than ten, and you should use a character class `[AP]` instead of an alternation `(?:A|P)`

It looks like you need

```
/\d{1,2}[AP]M/i
```

But you don't say what you want to *do* with the times once you have found them.

This snippet of code demonstrates the functionality by putting all the times that it finds in a string into array `@times` and then printing it with space separators.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $string (qw/ 9AM 9AM5PM 09AM05PM /) {
  my @times = $string =~ /\d{1,2}[AP]M/ig;
  print "@times\n";
}
```

**output**

```
9AM
9AM 5PM
09AM 05PM
```

If you really want to verify that the hour value is in range (are you likely to come across `35pm`?) then you could write

```
my @times = $string =~ / (?: 1[012] | 0?[1-9] ) [AP]M /igx
```

Note that the `/x` modifier makes whitespace insignificant within regular expressions, so that it can be used to clarify the form of the pattern.

Comment: What I'm actually doing is counting the occurrence of certain words/phrases etc inside a free form text blob to generate a vocabulary for certain filters, but I need to omit times, jargon etc.  Each word gets pushed into an array and checked to see if its a legitimate word or not.  In this case, the matches are ignored.

Comment: @RyanDunphy: Okay. Then everything hinges on what you mean by a *"word"*. It may work for you to just `split ' ', $string` and reject anything that contains digits, but you will have to give more information in a new question

Comment: @RyanDunphy: Like I said, you need to show your work in a new question and explain the problem you are having. Do you want to allow something like `3rd` as a word but reject `3pm`?

Comment: I am already ignoring anything that appears to be a number but the '9AM5PM' strings would make it through.  The actual value is irrelevant in this case. I had to make several regexes to catch phone numbers, mac addresses etc as well.  The best I can do is try to create some sort of context based on fixed values in other columns and manually parse out anything else that doesn't fit.  The goal is to define a vocabulary of relevant 'words' based on 1000 records and then compare that to a larger pool so I don't have to manually scrub everything.

Comment: You aren't helping yourself by asking new questions in comments. *Please* ask a new question showing all of your code and data. I don't see how you can write anything until you have defined what is a valid *"word"*. It is certainly the wrong way to go to identify which fields look like, say, a time, and rejecting them on that basis

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$string =~ /^((0?\d|1[0-2])[AP]M)+$/i;
```

As you can see [**here**](http://www.rubular.com/r/XxX5qUEks6). Or:

```
$string =~ /^((0?\d|1[0-2])[AP]M){1,2}$/i;
```

If you want it to be just up to 2 hours together.